# Cannot save list of objects in django sessions

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying modify session and store a list of model objects.

This is my view-

```
def update_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        cart = json.loads(post['cart'])
        food_list = []
        for f in cart['food']:
            food_list.append(Food.objects.get(food_id = f))
        print food_list
        request.session['food'] = food_list
        request.session.modified = True
        request.session['quantity'] = cart['quantity']
        request.session['price'] = cart['price']
        request.session['amount'] = cart['amount']
        print request.session
        return JsonResponse({'data': 'OK'})
```

It is printing the food_list and the session object as `<django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x7f49bca6e150>`

After this I am getting internal server error.

I also have `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` in my settings

Still I am unable to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the error you are getting. If it is an ajax request, you should be able to see it using your browser's dev tools, as long as you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings.

Answer (score 2):

Session wants something which is JSON serializable. So you have to adjust the following rule `food_list.append(Food.objects.get(food_id = f))` into append ids.

You could change the construction of the list into the following line. Also changes multiple gets on the DB into one filter.

```
food_list = [f.id for f in Food.objects.filter(food_id__in=cart['food'])]
```